# Questioning the use of prepositions in these sentences

Tags: prepositions

I do not know if the prepositions in these sentence are used correctly.

> "She questioned the sense in following that course of action."

and

> "The police questioned the suspect about whereabouts in the date in question."

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the use of prepositions in this sentence is correct:

> "She questioned the sense in following that course of action."

It could also have been written as

> "She questioned the sense **of** following that course of action."

Do you understand the statement? It means that "She" wondered/questioned whether following a certain "course of action" (series of steps or activities) was the right thing to do. The "sense" of it in this case means whether it made sense to follow those steps; in other words, were they the right steps to take?

In your second example, you might want to change it to read as follows:

> "The police questioned the suspect about **his** whereabouts **on** the date in question."

Again, the prepositions are used correctly. The question means, "Where was he when the crime occurred?" Can he account for where he was? Does he have an alibi or witness as to where he was? What was he doing on that day? I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Mark, 
Thanks for clarify the first sentence. Now it is clear.

Comment: Hi @lolocripto, Glad to help! That sentence was tricky. Thank you very much for your kind comment.